# Read a text file which has thousands of lines : read, validate and persist each line to different tables in multi threading mode using Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement, where I have to read a text file which has thousands of lines (each line is JSON object) .I need to read, validate the each line data and persist in to different tables(transnational --> persist full line or don't persist that line). 
Would spring batch is good for this requirement ..? If yes how to proceed.

How do i enable multi threading for line based reading, validating and persisting to Database if i use spring batch. Each line would be a separate thread.

Thinking of  writing service like this as below.

For each line asynchronously:
Read line, validate that line and persist that line so that memory usage is also less instead of loading all lines of file in to memory. (like each line is a separate thread)

How to proceed to implement this..?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can found all the answers reading official SB doc and doing tutorials (you can find on SB' home page as well as on external sites)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch is supposed to meet exactly those kind of requirements. To answer your first question - how to proceed: I recommend to go through some of the various tutorials available. Maybe you could try that one and extend it to your needs: [Spring Batch tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/).

Regarding the multi threading topic: Spring Batch has a bunch of concepts to execute an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) scenario in an efficient way. So here I would recommend to go through the very good documentation: [Spring Batch reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/).

Normally the build in "Chunking" can handle processing of thousands of lines without memory issues, if you follow the Reader -> Processor -> Writer pattern. If you feel you will need a more elaborated way of doing your work done, that you should go to Chapter 7. Scaling and Parallel Processing.

For implementing this I would stick to a traditional Reader -> Processor -> Writer pattern. Spring Batch provides a **JsonLineMapper** what might suitable here.